# Creating Custom Install USB

Tags: usb, custom-installer

I have a custom 12.04 DVD. But it doesn't complete installation due to some fault on the disk. Can I transfer these contents to a USB storage device and use that to install Ubuntu? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Insert your dvd and usb stick, prepare an iso by

```
cat <where your dvd folder, e.g. sth. like /dev/srX> ~/Desktop/xxxxx.iso
```

then put the iso into your usb

```
cat ~/Desktop/xxxxx.iso <where your usb device, e.g. sth. like /dev/sdX>
```

Or you can combine these two steps:

```
cat /dev/srX /dev/sdX
```

After writing, your usb is now an live usb!

Please note your should replease the X of srX and sdX into your correct label.
Please be very careful when you are trying to write sth. into /dev/sdX
Don't mess up your system disk.

Comment: but the dvd is displayed as file system

Comment: what did you mean 'the dvd is displaed as file system'?
would you please open a terminal and apply the command 'mount' when the DVD is in the DVD reader?

Answer (score 0):

First of all save the DVD as an ISO file

Then, ou can use Rufus software, download it from here http://rufus.akeo.ie/

Choose the the `Device` to be a flash disk

And for `Creat a bootable disk using` choose `ISO` and browse and choose your image

These are the important options

Click `Start` after that, when it's done you can boot from that flash disk

Comment: how do i save dvd as iso?

Comment: That depends on the platform you are running, I use UltrISO, you can install it, open the DVD from File menu, and then save as ISO

Comment: but dvd is diplayed as file system

Comment: The DVD is not readable at all?

Comment: i tried installing using it. but it went halfway till copying files. then it said error in disk

Comment: Try fixing your DVD http://news.yahoo.com/blogs/upgrade-your-life/fix-scratched-dvd-banana-175918542.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have ISO file, following links will helpful to you,

1 [create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

2 [create-a-usb-stick-on-windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

3 [FromUSBStickQuick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick)